# How can I update variable values in json body of a request (incrementing of time)

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

In Postman calls, how can I update variable values in json body of a request with increasing time. I need to call the endpoint for 2048 times. Each call should have the end_time with 5mins difference. I'm unable to convert the value to normal time format.

I wrote this:

```
var moment = require("moment");
var t = pm.variables.get("t");
pm.environment.set('t', moment().add(1000, 'seconds').valueOf(t));
console.log("t", t);
```

I see an error:

```
{
    "ErrorCode": "1100",
    "Message": "request.end_time: Error converting value \"1581351445025\" to type 'System.TimeSpan'. Path 'end_time', line 10, position 29."
}
```

Sample request: (In Body)

```
{
  "monday": true,
  "tuesday": true,
  "wednesday": true,
  "thursday": true,
  "friday": true,
  "saturday": false,
  "sunday": false,
  "start_time": "7:30:00",
  "end_time": "{{t}}",
  "start_date": "2020-01-23",
  "end_date": "2020-05-23"
}
```

Comment: in your example `pm.variables.get("t")` what format is `t` in?

Comment: It inserts the current Unix Time Stamp (Represented as the number of seconds) like "start_time": "1510934784"

Answer (score 0):

In `Pre-req` script view

```
var moment = require("moment");
var t = pm.variables.get("t");
console.log("t: " + t);
var newT = moment().add(1000, 'seconds').valueOf(t); 
console.log("newT: " + newT);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("newT", newT);
```

Then your request body should just change to use the new variable `{{newT}}`

Not sure why but using `pm.environment.set` wasn't setting the environment at all but `postman.setEnvironmentVariable` seems to work.

Comment: There is no change in the response. The value is still represented as the number of seconds.

Comment: You have to format it the way you want it with `.format('MM/DD/YYYY');`